# how to display all the chats Mesibo Android SDK

Tags: android, mesibo

I use Mesibo Android SDK. it is not clear how to programmatically list chat rooms in which the user participated? This is not in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "op = groupsget"